# Respond with javascript to an HTML request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, httprequest, response

Is it possible to respond to an HTML request with javascript? By this I mean that I don't want the page to be refreshed and plus execute some javascript code. I wonder if this is possible by changing only the server side?

In my action, I have something selected to respond to `js` and `html` like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.html
end
```

And I have a `.js.erb` file that, of course, should be rendered when the browser requests a javascript.

Can this be done? How?

Comment: looks good to me did you try calling that route with in js?

Comment: What do you mean? I need the request asks for an `html`, and the response be an `js`.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong. You want to do http://someurl.com/someroute and have it return js vs doing http://someurl.com/someroute.js ?

Comment: @DigitalCake you are correct!

Comment: that's strange, but have you tried in your route: `resources :some_resources, defaults: { format: :js }`?

Comment: I am not sure if you could also try `format.html { render 'your_file', format: :js }`

Comment: @juanpastas thanks, the first one don't work, the second gives me a missing template error with `:formats=>[:html]`, even specifying `js`.

Comment: my question is why? why not just call the url with the format .js ? would that not make more sense?

Comment: @DigitalCake updating from `rjs`, with a zilion places to change.

Comment: this gots code smell all over it.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this by only changing the server side code. If you'd like javascript to be executed upon the server's response, then the form will need to be submitted through javascript. This is because javascript will eval the response from the server and run the code.

This can somewhat be trivially added in Rails:

```
<%= form_for @user, remote: true %>
```

When it is submitted, then you can send back javascript. For example, to alert that a user was added:

/app/views/users/create.js.erb

```
alert("user <%= j @user.email %> was added");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also belive it is not possible. If no one come up with something, I will accept your answer. I understand that is easy, but I'm migrating from `rjs` (do you remember rjs?) to `ujs`, and so it is a lot of places to change this calls...